# Run multiple node apps on same server and domain

Tags: node.js, backend, microservices

I am wanting to split up an application I have into multiple different applications. I want to start with the presentation layer and the logical layer. I want the HTML, CSS and JS all in it's own application but then have the backend code (API) run in it's own application. I don't understand is how to run both on the same server. Currently my overgrown application runs on port 8080 and I use Nginx to do proxy_pass to port 8080 for the `/` location.

What do I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can run multiple instances of node,of course thats need to be a diferent version. Run in diferent ports and match with proxy_pass.
I Might help you.

Comment: That makes no sense. I can just change the port on one of the applications and then proxy pass that with say a location of `/api`. What I want to know is how to set this up inside my code.

Comment: Why you didnt first enable CORS (npm install cors --save and discard possible problems from CORS when you fetch data in the same domain) and maybe you can just handle your logic with req.get('/v1/some-action/param') and simple render your CSS,JS,CSS in front? req.get(''/",function(req,res){ res.render('index.ejs',{data})}) ? let me understand you better.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use view engines, such as EJS etc.

In *node.js* you can send HTML files to the user, so for example when some one visits *www.domain.com/register* you send him an HTML file, by using something like this:

```
var path = require('path'); // Core Module in Node JS
res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, "register.html" ) ); // Send the register HTML file
```

Although it wouldn't be the cleanest solution, *you could* also create *multiple* servers in the code, each using a different *port*.

Since you want a *Front End* and a *Back End* on the same server, you could make one server for the front end on port 80 ( and 443 if you are using SSL ) *and another server on a different port*, such as 3000, or whatever your heart desires.

You can then get info from the server with Ajax, or something similar, that is entirely up to you.

Here is an example:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('Front End!');
    res.end();
  }).listen(80);

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('Back End!');
    res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

I would personally always go with the first example, as it is what most people opt for, and it is much easier to implement.

Also, view engines allow you to embed variables from your *node.js* application into the HTML files, so there won't be any need for Ajax etc.

Comment: My project uses swig as my view/template engine already. I want to move to EJS but that is a major project. I am using express.js framework. so my routes are more app.get.....ect....   I will update the OP to reflect this.

Making one large application makes it hard to develop fast and deployment currently takes a half hour. Splitting it up into front and back is the start of making it more manageable

Comment: That doesn't change a thing, though. You can not run multiple instances of node on one machine, so you will have to combine then into one, using either one of the examples I gave.

Comment: I never said multiple instances of node. Multiple node applications, yes and I know you can do it for a fact. I have it running with multiple programs on a single node server at home. My question is how to use multiple node applications together. At home they are all on different subdomains because they don't relate.

Comment: I still don't quite understand you. Why not just run the front end on a different port than the back end? There is no need for the back end to run on port 80 or 443? Please elaborate.

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out. I have never ran multiple node apps on one server that needed to be connected together. it is not nearly as simple as just running both applications at the same time on the same server.   Request -> Nginx reverse proxy to node app

How can I have it so when both run the requests don't all get sent to the front end node app. I need the post, put and delete requests to pull from the back end node app. Do I set up location blocks like `/api` and then code my request//form routes how?

Comment: Well this is more of a ngnix question then, to be honest :) I am not too experienced with Ngnix, my apologies.